# PDO ошибка выборки c LIMIT

Tags: php, pdo

Почему выдает ошибку при таком запросе?

```
<?php 

    $num = 10;
    $start = 1;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users_for_events` LIMIT ?, ? ";
    $data = array($start, $num);
    $stmt = $this->getCon()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);
    $stmt->fetchAll();
    var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Ошибка вот такого плана:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1327 Undeclared variable: '1'' in

Comment: Этот код всегда быдет выводить пустой массив. fetchAll надо вызывать только один раз.

Comment: Понял! исправил

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[В режиме эмуляции все переданные через execute() переменные PDO подставляет в запрос как строки](http://phpdelusions.net/pdo#limit), и в итоге запрос получается

```
LIMIT '10', '1'
```

что вызывает ошибку. Самым простым решением будет отключить режим эмуляции сразу после соединения,

```
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

и после этого данный код сразу заработает без ошибок.

Comment: Это не всегда удачное решение. При отключенной эмуляции, подготовка запроса переходит в руки мускулу, а это увеличивает время выполнения запроса и иногда в раза два и больше. В принципе, я не вижу особых проблем, обработать значения для LIMIT, если таковые приходят извне, приведя их к типу integer и подставить в сам запрос без плейсхолдеров. А уж, если они прописаны вручную и статичны, то даже вопросов не должно возникать.

Comment: Все кто так рассуждает, рано или поздно приходят к инъекциям. программист не должен думать, извне пришли переменные, или не извне. И вручную обрабатывать тоже ничего не должен. А должен всегда следовать непреложному правилу - любая переменная должна попадать в запрос только через плейсхолдер. И не надо рассказывать сказки про увеличение времени выполнения запроса.

Comment: @Deonis что плохого в двукратном увеличении времени запроса?

Comment: @Etki если рассуждать абстрактно, то увеличение времени запроса - это всегда плохо. Но если говорить о реальности, то задержка там не  в два раза, и даже не в сто раз, а гораздо меньше.

Comment: @Etki, пусть вопросом на вопрос, но что в этом хорошего?

Comment: @Ипатьев, лично наблюдал увеличение времени практически в три раза. Да, скорее всего, что многое зависит от настроек сервера, но всё же.

Comment: @Deonis если верить "личным наблюдениям" РНР пользователей, так и крокодилы летают. И дело не тут не в каких-то мифических настройках сервера, а в банальном неумении ставить эксперименты и делать из них логически безупречные выводы.

Comment: @Ипатьев, о каких экспериментах идёт речь, если это было проверено на реальных проектах. Впрочем, пусть каждый сам для себя решает.

Comment: @Deonis в данном случае - испарение костылей. Подстановка данных в запрос - это условная константа, поэтому такую же условную сложность алгоритма и время выполнения она на самом деле не меняет. Разница во времени запроса в 2 мс и в 6 мс никакой роли не играет.

Comment: @Ипатьев это вполне выгодный tradeoff за возможность пользоваться человеческими вещами.